# 'Use Case Feed' option on developer org

Tags: administration, developer-edition, casefeed

I setup a developer org to test Case Feeds.  When I try and edit a profile, I cannot see the 'Use Case Feed' option under General Permissions.  How can I get access to that permission?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [SF Help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=case_interaction_custom_profiles.htm&language=en_US):

> Case Feed is automatically enabled and assigned to all standard profiles in Salesforce organizations created after the Winter ’14 release. To disable Case Feed on a profile, deselect Use Case Feed.

Answer (score 0):

Before the "Use Case Feed" checkbox is available on the Profile, make sure you do the following:

Enable Feed Tracking on the Case object
*Setup > Chatter > Feed Tracking > Cases > √*

Activate Feed Actions/Items in Support Settings
*Setup > Cases > Support Settings > Enable Case Feed Actions and Feed Items √*